# Как принудительно установить autofocus при каждом открытии popup?

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть попап. В нём строка поиска. При загрузке страницы автофокус срабатывает. Но, после открытия и закрытия попапа, например 3 раза автофокус не срабатывает. Как мне его установить принудительно, кликнув по определённому элементу страницы?

```js
"use strict";
(function($){
    $(function(){
        var elem;
        $(document).on('mouseover','.search_btn',function(){
            $('.search_input').focus(function() {
                console.log('test');

            });
            $('main').removeClass('custom_no_blur').addClass('custom_blur');
            $('.pmc').css({'display':'block'});
            $('.popup').fadeIn(800);
            $('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio').parent().parent().css({'background-color':'rgba(0,128,0,0.3)','border-radius':'5px','color':'darkgreen'});
            $('.block_label__item').on('mouseover',function(){
                $(this).css({'background-color':'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.3)','border-radius':'5px','color':'darkgreen'});
            });
            $('.block_label__item').on('mouseout',function(){
                elem=$(this).children().children();
                if ($(elem[1]).attr('checked')!='checked'){
                    $(this).css({'background-color':'white','color':'#ccc'});
                }
            });
            $('.block_label__item').on('click',function(){
                elem=$(this).children().children();
                var name=$(elem[1]).attr('name');
                var mas_input=$('.block_label__item input[name="'+name+'"]');
                for(let i=0; i<mas_input.length;i++){
                    $(mas_input[i]).attr('checked',false);
                }
                $('.block_label__item input[name="'+name+'"]').parent().parent().css({'background-color':'white','color':'#ccc'});
                $(elem[1]).attr('checked',true);
                $('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio').parent().parent().css({'background-color':'rgba(0,128,0,0.3)','border-radius':'5px','color':'darkgreen'});
            });
            function sendPostAndAnimate(){
                var input=$('.block_label__item input[checked="checked"]:radio');
                var searchStr=$('.search_input').val();
                var searchField=$(input[0]).val();
                var searchStatusId=$(input[1]).val();
                var searchSort=$(input[2]).val();
                if (searchField=='none'&searchStatusId=='0'){
                   $('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
                   $('.popup').fadeOut(800,function(){$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
                   $('.loader-container').fadeIn(300);
                   let url='/project/searchAjax/';
                   $.post(url,{searchStr:searchStr,searchField:searchField,searchStatusId:searchStatusId,searchSort:searchSort},function(data){
                       $('.blocks .table tbody').html(data);
                       $('.pagination').hide();
                       $('.loader-container').fadeOut(300,function(){$('.blocks .table tbody').ready().ajaxComplete();});
                    });
                }else{
                    if(searchStr.length>2){
                       $('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
                       $('.popup').fadeOut(800,function(){$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
                       $('.loader-container').fadeIn(300);
                       let url = '/project/searchAjax/';
                       $.post(url,{searchStr:searchStr,searchField:searchField,searchStatusId:searchStatusId,searchSort:searchSort},function(data){
                           $('.blocks .table tbody').html(data);
                           $('.pagination').hide();
                           $('.loader-container').fadeOut(300,function(){$('.blocks .table tbody').ready().ajaxComplete();});
                        });
                    }else{alert('Запрос должен быть не менее 3-х символов!');}
                }
            }
            $('.search_input').keydown(function(event){if(event.keyCode===13){sendPostAndAnimate();}});
            $('.popup__footer__submit').on('click',function(){sendPostAndAnimate();});
            function setDefaultPropClosePopup(){
                $('main').removeClass('custom_blur').addClass('custom_no_blur');
                $('.popup').fadeOut(800,function () {$('.pmc').css({'display':'none'});});
                $('.search_input').off();
                $('.popup__footer__submit').off();
                $('.search_input').focus(false);
            }
            $('.pmc_close').on('click',function(){setDefaultPropClosePopup();});
            $('.popup_close').on('click',function (){setDefaultPropClosePopup();});
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

html:

```
<div class="pmc">
    <div class="pmc_close"></div>
    <div class="popup_container">
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="popup__navigation">
                <div class="popup__navigation__search">
                    <input class="search_input" type="text" name="search_input" value="" placeholder="Ваш поисковый запрос" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus">
                </div>
                <div class="popup_close" title="Закрыть">
                    X
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup__search">
                <div class="popup__search__block">
                    <div class="popup__search_text">
                        <h2> Где искать?</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__search__block">
                    <div class="popup__search_select">
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_1" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">№ Брони</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="id">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_2" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Дата</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="date">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_3" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Дилер</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="dealer">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_4" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Менеджер</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value=manager>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_5" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Бренд</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="brend">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search_select">
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_7" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">ИНН ЮЛ</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="ur_inn">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_8" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Адрес</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="address" checked="checked">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_9" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Оборудование</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="tool">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_10" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Комментарий к проекту</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="comment_by_project">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_11" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Не учитывать</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="field" value="none">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__search__block">
                    <div class="popup__search_text">
                        <h2> Учитавать статус?</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__search__block">
                    <div class="popup__search_select">
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_12" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Не учитывать</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="0" checked="checked">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_13" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Не обработано</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="1">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_14" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизовано</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="2">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_15" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Не авторизовано</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="3">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_16" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Реализовано</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="4">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_17" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Не реализовано</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="5">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="popup__search_select">
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_18" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизация прекращена</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="6">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_19" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизация продлена</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="7">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_20" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Авторизация просрочена</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="8">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_21" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Запрос актуальности</span>
                                    <input class="select_status" style="display:none;" type="radio" name="select_status" value="9">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__search__block">
                    <div class="popup__search_text">
                        <h2> Порядок вывода?</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="popup__search__block">
                    <div class="popup__search_select">
                        <div class="block_label">
                            <div id="bli_22" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Возрастание</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="sort" value="asc">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div id="bli_23" class="block_label__item">
                                <label class="label_select_fild">
                                    <span class="label_select_fild__text">Убывание</span>
                                    <input style="display:none;" type="radio" name="sort" value="desc" checked="checked">
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="popup__footer">
                <div class="popup__footer__item">
                    <input class="popup__footer__submit" type="button" name="popup__footer__submit" value="Найти">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для начала - показать код. По словесному описанию помочь сможет примерно никто.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko `примерно никто` + за иронию

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko
Пример:
<div class="popup">
<input class="my_input" value="" autofocus>
</div>
JS:
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    $(".popup").onclick(function(){ $(".my_input").focus();});
Не работает.

Comment: @doox911  наверно не onclick а  `$(object).on("click", function({здесь код})` или `$(window).on("click",".my_input", function(){здесь код})`

Comment: @НикитаФаст $('body').on('mouseover','.search_btn',function(){
            $('.search_input').focus();
}); Не работает.
.search_input' - класс у input

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос, пожалуйста. Там под вопросом есть кнопка `править`.

Comment: не боди а документ

Comment: Поставьте `console.log()` в обработчик события. Событие срабатывает? Также было бы отлично, если бы привели соответствующий `html` код.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Да. срабатывает (mouseover).

Comment: @НикитаФаст Не работает. Да и в чём разница?

Comment: с `document` не работает а с `body` срабатывает ?

Comment: @НикитаФаст _mouseover_ срабатывает так и так. А вот             $('.search_input').focus(function() {
                console.log('test'); 
            }); Ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переместил

```
$('.search_input').focus();
```

после

```
$('.pmc').css({'display':'block'});
```

Если input лежит в блоке с display:none, то фокус не может установиться.

Comment: я ответ давать не буду  - выбери лучшим ответ Степана

Comment: Так ответ Степана не верен. А твой ответ помог в решении вопроса (частично). @НикитаФаст

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать что-то определенное без полного примера, воспроизводящего ошибку.

Вот такое решение в 90% случаев должно сработать.

```
$('body').on('click','.search_btn',function(){ 
   setTimeout(()=>$('.search_input').focus(), 500);
});
```

Comment: Не сработало как у вас выше, так и это не срабатывает:
    $('.search_input').focus(function() {
       console.log('test');
    });

Comment: $('.search_input').focus(function() { console.log('test'); }); Срабатывает только 1 раз. А нужно всегда.

Comment: @doox911 добавь tabindex и второй после фокуса надо курсор отвести и потом опять навести и тыкнуть так как фокус это уже состояние

Comment: @doox911 Так вам что надо? Что бы фокус был на `input` после нажатия на кнопку или что бы событие `focus` на `input` всегда срабатывало?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Что бы фокус был на input после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: @doox911 Тогда зачем вы путаете нас с событием `focus`? Показывайте ваш `html` код. Потому что приведенный код должен работать, если конечно у вас там какой-то совсем невероятной магии не происходит после нажатия на кнопку

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Подправил вопрос

Comment: @doox911  у тебя в коде где то ошибка , я вынес код с input в самый низ и он заработал : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yRvoep

Comment: @doox911  скрин от работы в кодепен :https://www.dropbox.com/s/mdocfbx0tr2c1te/2018-10-17_175646.png?dl=0

Comment: @НикитаФаст Вы правы. Буду Искать.

Comment: @НикитаФаст переместил $('.search_input').focus(); после $('main').removeClass('custom_no_blur').addClass('custom_blur'); и всё заработало.

Comment: @doox911 вот в чем польза полного кода, воспроизводящего проблему. Если у вас возникнут вопросы в будущем, то сразу выкладывайте код. Рад, что у вас получилось найти ошибку.